# Can you deserialize an instance of an interface without its type definition?

Tags: c#, binaryformatter

Let's say I have a serialized bytes of an instance of an interface, `AnInterface`, like so:

```
AnInterface instance = new ConcreteClass();
serializeToDatabase(instance);
```

Is it possible to do something like:

```
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
byte[] bytes = bytesSavedToDB;
stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
stream.Position = 0;
AnInterface instance = (AnInterface) formatter.Deserialize(stream);
```

without having the definition for `ConcreteClass`?

Comment: No you can not, you need the underlying type.

Comment: What is preventing you from knowing the Type of the serialized class?

Comment: BinaryFormatter uses Object.GetType(), you can't hide the fact that it really *is* a ConcreteClass.  Intentionally obfuscating it isn't a very good idea, you really, really care about the concrete class if you hope the deserialize again a year from now or on another machine.  At which point the *exact* same version of ConcreteClass needs to be available again.

Answer (score 2):

BinaryFormatter saves information about the types into the binary stream. It uses that information to reconstruct the object graph during deserialization. So, you can deserialize the stream without knowing what object it contains.

However, all the concrete classes that were serialized should be loadable during deserialization. In practice, this means that the assemblies that hold them should be either in the application folder, GAC, or loaded into memory by other means.

`formatter.Deserialize` returns just the `object`, that you can cast to an interface or to concrete type.

Comment: Also a important note for `BinaryFormatter` is the classes that are deserialized must also be considered "the same version" by the BinaryFormatter. If it detects metadata differences it will fail to deserialize.

Answer (score -1):

You can not deserialize this without knowing the (real) type of the class.

Comment: You _can_ generate a dynamic type though (which implements the interface) and deserialize to that.

Comment: It is completely possible to do this using reflection. "Knowing" atcompile time is not necessary.